# Capitalize words without built-in JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript, html, uppercase

I want capitalize words in a string like...

```
Hello World, New York, First Name
```

...with JavaScript. But the trick is this I don't want to use any **built-in JavaScript functions** like `toUpperCase`, `split`, `join`, etc. I have made one sample program but got stuck.

```
var myString = "Hello world!";
var myArray = [];
var out= ""
for (var i=0; i < myString.length; i++){
    myArray.push(myString[i]);
    if(myString[i] == " "){
        continue;
    }
alert(myString[i])
}
```

This doesn't use `split`. I have converted my string in `array` and then I search for a blank array with `continue`.

Please don't recommend using CSS attributes such as `text-transform:uppercase`. I know all these. I want to do this with *JavaScript only*.

Comment: I have a little tool on my own site that I use for "title case" any block of text:  http://dpoisn.com/tools.php.  Just view the source on that.  It's all right there.

Comment: So you want to write `"Hello world".replace(/(^| )./g, function(a){return a.toUpperCase()})` but more complicated? Briefly: forget about the `myArray`, iterate each character as you do, and check if it is either the start of the `string (i=0)` or preceeded by whitespace `(myString[i-1]==" ")`. If so, change the character to uppercase. Then append the character to `out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myString = "Hello world!";
var myStringAux = "";

for (var i=0; i < myString.length; i++){
    if(i==0 || myString[i-1] == " ") {
       switch(myString[i]) {
        case "a":
            myStringAux+="A";
            break;
        case "h":
            myStringAux+="H";
            break;
        case "w":
            myStringAux+="W";
            break;
        default:
            myStringAux+= myString[i];
           break; 
           }


    } else {
       myStringAux+=myString[i];

    }



}
myString = myStringAux;
alert(myString)
```

Also fiddle for playing: https://jsfiddle.net/22xken1e/

You can also do it converting to ascii to avoid cases, but I don't know if you can use this functions

```
    var myString = "Hello world!";
var myStringAux = "";

for (var i=0; i < myString.length; i++){ 
    if((i==0 || myString[i-1] == " ") && 97<= myString[i].charCodeAt(0) && myString[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 122 ) {
       myStringAux += String.fromCharCode(myString[i].charCodeAt(0) - 32)

    } else {
       myStringAux+=myString[i];

    }

}
alert(myStringAux)
```

Comment: its giving undefined and hello world string is just example

Comment: See the edit. You should do cases for all the letters

Comment: your are the MAN Del great work buddy..i would gave u like but my reputaion is low ...thanks man

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: sorry but can i ask one more think cant we make these cases bit optimized like its getting too big

Comment: cant we do this with the help of ascii values

Comment: If you can't use that, you can not avoid the cases without using more complex functions

Comment: thanks man!!! actually m doing this to improve my coding logic and skills as i am unable to find exercise for javascript and coding